# Property does not exist on type 'Object' Error with Typescript

Tags: typescript

I made config.ts file as below.

```
export interface IDBConfig {
  username: string;
  password: string;
  database: string;
  host: string;
  dialect: string;
}

class Config {
  private DBConfig: IDBConfig;

  constructor() {
    this.DBConfig = {
      username: "",
      password: "",
      database: "",
      host: "",
      dialect: "",
    };
  }

  public getDBConfig(environment: string): Object {
    switch (environment) {
      case "local":
        this.DBConfig = {
          username: "root",
          password: "1234",
          database: "test",
          host: "127.0.0.1",
          dialect: "mysql",
        };
        break;
    }
    return this.DBConfig;
  }
}

export { Config };
```

And I imported this config in sequelize.ts file. 
'console.log(dBConfig) gives me the object of DBConfig without problem.
But the next line gives me a error says property 'database' does not exist on type 'Object'.
'username', 'password', 'host' also have same problem.

```
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize";
import { Config } from "./config";

class SequelizeRun {
  private sequelize: object;

  constructor() {
    this.sequelize = {};
  }

  public getSequelize() {
    const config = new Config();
    const dBConfig = config.getDBConfig("local");

    console.log(dBConfig);

    this.sequelize = new Sequelize(
      dBConfig.database,
      dBConfig.username,
      dBConfig.password,
      {
        host: dBConfig.host,
        dialect: "mysql",
        timezone: "+00:00",
        pool: {
          max: 30,
          min: 0,
          acquire: 30000,
          idle: 10000,
        },
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Could you give me some solution for this? Thank you for reading this.

Comment: You declared `getDBConfig()` to return `Object`. It has no `database` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public getDBConfig(environment: string): IDBConfig {
    switch (environment) {
      case "local":
        this.DBConfig = {
          username: "root",
          password: "1234",
          database: "test",
          host: "127.0.0.1",
          dialect: "mysql",
        };
        break;
    }
    return this.DBConfig;
  }
```

try this one.